# Javascript: binding to the right of a function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How can I bind to the right of the function? Example:

```
var square = Math.pow.bindRight(2);
console.log(square(3)); //desired output: 9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for partial functions, which are convenient shorthands for aliases.

The "classic" way to do what you're asking for is with:

```
var square = function (x) {
  return Math.pow(x, 2);
};
```

Using partial functions it would be:

```
var square = Math.pow.partial(undefined, 2);
console.log(square(3));
```

Unfortunately, `Function.prototype.partial` isn't provided in any browser.

---

Fortunately for you, I've been working on a library of what I consider to be *essential* JavaScript object oriented functions, methods, classes, etc. This is `Function.prototype.partial.js`:

```
/**
 * @dependencies
 * Array.prototype.slice
 * Function.prototype.call
 * 
 * @return Function
 * returns the curried function with the provided arguments pre-populated
 */
(function () {
    "use strict";
    if (!Function.prototype.partial) {
        Function.prototype.partial = function () {
            var fn,
                argmts;
            fn = this;
            argmts = arguments;
            return function () {
                var arg,
                    i,
                    args;
                args = Array.prototype.slice.call(argmts);
                for (i = arg = 0; i < args.length && arg < arguments.length; i++) {
                    if (typeof args[i] === 'undefined') {
                        args[i] = arguments[arg++];
                    }
                }
                return fn.apply(this, args);
            };
        };
    }
}());
```

Comment: I had not seen this answer before. This is actually the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: See also lodash `partialRight()` solution in @brian-m-hunt answer below

Answer (score 13):

```
Function.prototype.bindRight = function() {
    var self = this, args = [].slice.call( arguments );
    return function() {
        return self.apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments ).concat( args ) );
    };
};

var square = Math.pow.bindRight(2);
square(3); //9
```

Comment: I was actually expecting an implementation using the standard library, or a popular library. It seems like there is not, though, so this is the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Lodash's [`partialRight`](http://lodash.com/docs#partialRight) will do what you want, and here is the documentation:

```
This method is like _.partial except that partial arguments
are appended to those provided to the new function.

Arguments
      func   (Function): The function to partially apply arguments to.
      [arg]  (…*)      : Arguments to be partially applied.
Returns      (Function): Returns the new partially applied function.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you want partial application. There are a number of libraries that provide that, including underscore.js: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`partial` from underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#partial), by passing `_` as a placeholder, to be filled-in later:

```
var square = _.partial(Math.pow, _, 2);
console.log(square(3)); // => 9
```

This feature appeared in February 2014 (underscore [1.6.0](http://underscorejs.org/#1.6.0)).

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with:

```
var square = function(x) {return x*x;};
```

To answer the question properly, you need to create an anonymous function that calls the "bound" function with a set parameter, such as:

```
var square = function(x) {return Math.pow(x,2);};
```

In this manner, you can bind any number of parameters, rearrange parameters, or a combination of the two. However bear in mind that there is some impact to performance, as you are adding an extra function call to the stack every time you bind like this.

Comment: Do you mean except with the fact that he asking for something else?

Comment: I'm going to have to assume, then, that it's a bad example, since this answer very clearly resolves the problem in the example given.

Comment: The example given was not the case to be solved, it was merely an example so you could understand what I need. Sorry, but this won't do it, even though the intention is good.

Comment: Answered properly. Hope that's better now.

Comment: I think Dokkat was asking for a generic implementation of bindRight. It's pretty trivial to write it for a specific function.

Comment: It is better, but still not the answer.